# Read a PKCS12 example using Bouncy Castle LW API only

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, jce, pkcs#12

I'm trying to open a PKCS12-DEF file without using the JCE/JCA. Until now I've managed to get by using tests as examples of how to do everything with Bouncy Castle.

But I have failed to see any example that does not use the java.security.Keystore class which is no good for my purposes.

Can anybody point me to the right direction?

Thanks in advance.